# JS setInterval not starting right away but otherwise working well

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Can someone tell me why using this setInterval takes 15 seconds to start running and how to make it run without delay? It works well in repeating every 15 seconds like it should but I want to remove the start

```
function pollServer() {
    intervalId = window.setInterval(function ()  {
        callE();
        callA();
        callC();
        callB();
        callD();
        
     }, 15000);  
    
 }
 pollServer();
```

Comment: `setInterval()` does not run immediately, only after your specified delay

Comment: I see and the default is apparently just to use whatever the interval is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fix this, call the function before setting the interval like this:

```
function foo() {
    callE();
    callA();
    callC();
    callB();
    callD();
}
foo();
setInterval(foo, 15000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use setTimeout function

```js
pollServer();
function pollServer() {
  
        callE();
        callA();
        callC();
        callB();
        callD();
     setTimeout(pollServer(), 15000);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not a problem, setInterval work exactly like that.You have to use different methods to work around that-Run the function once, and then set the interval inside it.

```
function runOnInterval()  {
        callE();
        callA();
        callC();
        callB();
        callD();
        
     }

function pollServer() {
    runOnInterval(); 
    intervalId = window.setInterval(runOnInterval, 15000);   
 }
 pollServer();
```

The function is invoked immediately, and then the timer is set(waiting for the interval till the next invocation).